# date time set to calendar with specific time zone not giving correct convert date time of other time zone in java

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-conversion, java.util.calendar

Here I am giving parameters like month, date, hourofday, seconds like(2,14,11,0), first setting zonevalue (IST).

```
    Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    localTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneValue));
    localTime.set(2018, month, date, hourofday,minutes,seconds);
```

In the below code short name is other time zone, ex: "PST", after setting first calendar to this below calendar I am not getting valid date time related to first calendar parameters.

```
    Calendar germanyTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(shortName));
    germanyTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
```

Our company is still using java 1.6.

Please help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: “Local” in date-time handling means *any* locality not any one locality. So “localTime“ is not a good name for your variable here.

Answer (score 1):

Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed many times already. And read the Oracle Tutorial. So briefly here…

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34, 56 , 0 , ZoneId.of( “Asia/Kolkata” ) ) 
    .withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( “Europe/Berlin” ) )
```

## java.time

Use modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome legacy date-time classes you used.

### `ZonedDateTime`

Pass those arguments to `ZonedDateTime.of` rather than legacy  `Calendar`.

### `ZoneId`

For the time zone, pass `ZoneId` object, not legacy `TimeZone`.

Never use 3-4 letter pseudo-zones like “PST” and “CST” and “IST”. Always use proper time zone names in continent/region format such as `America/Los_Angeles` or `Africa/Tunis`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34, 56 , 0 , ZoneId.of( “Asia/Kolkata” ) ) ;
```

Adjust into another zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( “Europe/Berlin” ) ) ;
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `ZonedDateTime::toString`. For other formats use `DateTimeFormatter` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Basil but our company is still using java 1.6,so i cannot use ZonedDateTime class here

Comment: @TarunSingh Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.